# Want to show the name of the user who add the comment

Tags: laravel, session, comments

i am new to Laravel , in my project i want to add a comment in the blog after the authentification , i use session with this , so the problem is he don't show the name of the user  !

this is my controller comment :

```
public function store  (blog $getid , Request $request)
{
    $patient_id=$request->session()->get('patient_id');
     comment::create([
        'body' =>request('body'),
        'blog_id'=> $getid->id,
        'patient_id'=>$patient_id
    ]);

     return back();
}
```

This is the show.blade.php :

```
 @foreach ($showme->comments as $comment)
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p style="font-size:15px;">{{$comment->body}}</p>
      <p> {{$comment->patient_id}}</p>

      <footer class="blockquote-footer"> {{$comment->created_at}} <cite title="Source Title"> </cite></footer>


    </blockquote>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <!-- si le patient est connceter -->
  @if(Session::has('log_in'))
    <div class="card-block">
   <form method="POST" action="/blog/{{$showme->id}}/store" >
   @csrf
   <div class="form-group">
   <label> Commentaire </label> </br>
   <textarea name="body"  rows="3" cols="80" cols="form-control"></textarea> </br>
    </div><div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Ajouter commentaire</button>
</div>
  </form>
</div>
@endif
```

**WEB.PHP**

```
Route::Post('/store' , 'patientcontroller@store');
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I guess you have an User model, and patient_id is related to User->id so you have to refer to that model, instead patient_id. Anyway if you are using default Laravel auth system, you can get information about your logged user as {{ Auth::user()->name }}

Comment: Yees i forget about the model to add the patient_id , now it's work thank you

Comment: Glad to help. Enjoy your Laravel trip!